# Could I create FlowFields dynamically with C/AL code?

Tags: navision

I am new with Nav and I would know how to create objects, like FlowFields, dynamically with C/AL code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Privet new with Nav, you can't.

You cannot create any standard objects dynamically. No tables, no fields, no reports, no codeunits.

If you lucky enough to have Nav 2013 or newer then you can create .Net objects.

Welcome to h.... Nav!

Comment: Ok, 2MAk Sim Thank you